# Displaying only a part of graph using Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using Achartengine to generate TimeChart graph. The data set consists of dates form 1/15/2003 to 12/4/2040 (x-axis) with respective random values for Y-axis. I am displaying the graph dynamically where I keeps reading the values on background thread (AsyncTask) and repaints the graphview. I have 2 questions:

1. The view starts from Jan, 2, 1970(I dono why) and I have to scroll to  1/15/2003 to see the graph. What should I change to make it start from 1/15/2003 ?
2. Also I take 2 date values FROM and TO (Eg: FROM:2/17/2004 TO:6/23/2006) and I want to display the graph only in this range. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I understood why its starting to display form Jan, 2, 1970 that is because I add points to the data set  using dataset.add(Date x, double y) and  I create Data objects as new Data(String y) and this considers date rage from Jan, 2, 1970.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the 1st one using mRenderer.setYAxisMin(new Date("1/15/2003  11:16:00 AM").getTime()) Although this is a deprecated method, but it did the work for me. Now when I display the graph its starts from given data not Jan, 2, 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set Y axis min and max with values desired values, just before repainting.

And for the 1. question, maybe better option is to set pan limits, so you can't scroll to empty parts of your chart. 
You can do it like this

```
mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax});
```

where you calculate limits like this

```
double xMin = minDate.getTime();
double xMax = maxDate.getTime();
```